# Was the Monster Lore Compendium ever updated after April 6th, 2008?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, online-resources

Was the Monster Lore Compendium ever updated after April 6th, 2008? If so, where can it be found?

I have read that it was going to be [added to the d20pfsrd](https://web.archive.org/web/20100625000407/http://community.wizards.com:80/go/thread/view/75882/19546370/Monster_Lore_Compendium?pg=63#380151261) (yes, d20pfsrd, even though this is a 3.5e resource), though I don't think that ever happened.

I know it was put into a spreadsheet [here](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=11296.0) but I don't believe that any updates were added.

Comment: d20pfsrd is a site dedicated to Pathfinder resources. Do you perhaps mean d20srd?

Comment: @Maiko Chikyu I changed the link to show the post that states what I said, and yes it's d20pfsrd. I remember some monsters having the monster lore added there, if I recall correctly.

Comment: I've started a discussion about this question [on meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8694/how-should-we-fix-the-monster-lore-compendium-question). The question is about a 3.5 resource, but the claim linked in the question really does say it was going to be added to d20pfsrd (a PF site).

Answer (score 2):

### No, it wasn't.

Since it's inception in 08/13/2006, the Monster Lore Compendium was hosted in the main WotC forums at:

```
http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19546370/Monster_Lore_Compendium
```

Last version accesible in the wayback machine: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101206121113/http://community.wizards.com:80/go/thread/view/75882/19546370/Monster_Lore_Compendium).

Between 07/12/2011 and 12/09/2013 the WotC forums underwent a redesign, but threads from old editions were kept, and the new address for the Monster Lore Compendium became:

```
http://community.wizards.com/forum/previous-editions-general/threads/1074581
```

Last version accesible in the wayback machine: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150928082040/http://community.wizards.com:80/forum/previous-editions-general/threads/1074581).

Then between the September 28th and November 18th of 2015 the post became no longer accessible.

The last "official" update to it's contents was made by the OP, Evandar_TAybara, on April 6th, 2008.

---

Regarding the port from the WotC forums to d20pfsrd mentioned by Voxaminer on the last reply to the thread, **it did happen**.

Several bestiary entries on [www.d20pfsrd.com](http://www.d20pfsrd.com) were updated to include the contents from the Monster Lore Compendium at some point, and they were later rolled back, removing that content.

An example of this can be observed in this user's [thread](https://www.thepiazza.org.uk/bb/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=8797) on The Piazza forums from 2012, where he indicates that the Ankheg entry was updated to include the Monster Lore Compendium data, yet today that information [isn't present](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/ankheg).

Only two entries in the d20pfsrd's bestiary remain today that include data from the Monster Lore Compendium, they are the [Devourer](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/devourer/) and the [Triceratops](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/dinosaur/triceratops/).

However, I have found a clone of [www.d20pfsrd.com](http://www.d20pfsrd.com) that still contains the data from the Monster Lore Compendium for most entries, at https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/.

For example, the creature mentioned previously, the Ankheg, still has the Monster Lore Compendium information in this page, as seen [here](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/ankheg). The search function doesn't work though, as the results link back to the real d20pfsrd page, so in order to browse the creature entries you have to go to the bestiary index on the left and search for the creature manually.